# \AtBeginDocument and \AtEndDocument for standalone

Tags: standalone, hooks

Using the commands `\AtBeginDocument` and `\AtEndDocument` with the `standalone` documentclass yields unexpected effects.

I have the following three files.

```
% main.tex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[subpreambles]{standalone}
\AtBeginDocument{begin main \\}
\AtEndDocument{end main \\}
\begin{document}%
  before
  \input{sub1}
  between
  \input{sub2}
  after
\end{document}
```

and

```
% sub1.tex
\documentclass{standalone}    
\AtBeginDocument{begin sub1 \\}
\AtEndDocument{end sub1 \\}
\begin{document}%
\end{document}
```

`sub2.tex` looks like `sub1.tex` except for the numbers. Compiling `main.tex` results in a document that orders the text fragments like this. (I inserted some indentation here just to point out the structure.)

```
begin sub1
 begin sub2
  begin main
   before
   between
   after
  end main
 end sub1
end sub2
```

But I would expect this.

```
begin main
 before
  begin sub1
  end sub1
 between
  end sub2
  begin sub2
 after
end main
```

How can I instead get the second result?

Comment: How important is it that the sub-files use `\At<etc>` commands?  It would be easy to create a `\myimport` command that optionally executes something before and/or after each actual call of `\input` in a way that preserves the desired output structure.

Comment: I am assuming you want the expected output to be "between, begin sub2, end sub2" and not how you have it written.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure there are better ways of doing this, but my approach is to patch the `\AtBeginDocument` and `\AtEndDocument` macros during the loading of the subpreambles such that they append their arguments to temporary macros. I then patch the `input` (or more specifically `\@iinput`) macro to use the temporary macros in the document body. I do the patching with the [`etoolbox`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex2e/contrib/etoolbox/) package, but you can do it however you want. In order to get the patching done during the loading of the subpreambles I write directly into the `\jobname.sta` file. My patching of `\@iinput` isn't particularly robust and requires you to use `\input{sub1.tex}` instead of `\input{sub1}.

By the way this type of patching of the `\AtBeginDocument` and `\AtEndDocument` macros is going to cause havoc if you load any packages in your sub files that depend on `\AtBeginDocument` and `\AtEndDocument` being expanded where they are supposed to be expanded.

```
% main.tex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[subpreambles]{standalone}
\AtBeginDocument{begin main \\}
\AtEndDocument{end main \\}


\makeatletter
\pretocmd{\@iinput}{\csuse{AtBeginDocument#1}}{}{}
\apptocmd{\@iinput}{\csuse{AtEndDocument#1}}{}{}
{\@makeother\#%
    \AtBeginDocument{\immediate\write\sa@out{\unexpanded{%
        \renewcommand{\subpreamble}[1]{%
            \expandafter\def\csname AtBeginDocument#1\endcsname{}%
            \expandafter\def\csname AtEndDocument#1\endcsname{}%
            \renewcommand{\AtBeginDocument}[1]{\expandafter\apptocmd\expandafter{\csname AtBeginDocument#1\endcsname}{##1}{}{}}
            \renewcommand{\AtEndDocument}[1]{\expandafter\apptocmd\expandafter{\csname AtEndDocument#1\endcsname}{##1}{}{}}
        }
    }}}
}
\makeatother

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}%

  before

  \input{sub1.tex}

  between

  \input{sub2.tex}

  after

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since someone provided the tricky answer (+1), I don't feel bad about suggesting the simple answer, which may or may not be helpful depending on what you *really* want to happen near the 'edges' or your sub-files.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\parindent 0pt
\usepackage[subpreambles]{standalone}
\AtBeginDocument{main.tex: begin main\par}
\AtEndDocument{main.tex:   end main\par}

\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\myinput}{omo}
{\IfNoValueTF{#3}%
  {\IfNoValueTF{#1}%
    {\input{#2}}%
    {#1\par\input{#2}}}%
  {\IfNoValueTF{#1}%
    {\input{#2}\par#3\par}%
    {#1\par\input{#2}\par#3\par}}%
}

\begin{document}%

before

\myinput{sub1}

between

\myinput[sub1: before (no after)]{sub1}

between

\myinput{sub1}[sub1: after (no before) ]

between

\myinput[sub2: before]{sub2}[sub2: after]

\end{document}
```

Then remove all the `\At<etc.>` arguments from your sub-files:

```
% sub1.tex
\documentclass{standalone}
% \AtBeginDocument{begin sub1 \\}
% \AtEndDocument{end sub1 \\}
\begin{document}%
sub1 -- main text
\end{document}
```

and

```
% sub1.tex
\documentclass{standalone}
% \AtBeginDocument{begin sub2 \\}
% \AtEndDocument{end sub2 \\}
\begin{document}%
sub2 -- main text
\end{document}
```

Comment: This doesn't work in the sense that if you compile the sub1 on its own you lose the before/after code.

Comment: @DanielE.Shub -- Not necessarily: `standalone` has commands like `\ifstandalone` which would easily solve that problem, depending on what the `\At<etc.>` stuff is supposed to do.  I was merely waiting to see what that code really was before worrying about it.  I assume it's not just a matter of inserting text in an awkward sort of way....